# How do you make chainmail armor in minecraft PE survival?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft PE and don't know how to make chainmail armor. I have seen it in creative but not in survival.

Comment: I think it's only obtainable in creative (at least without mods)

Answer (score 5):

Chainmail armor is not craftable in survival mode. You can only find it in loot chests in villages or as drop from Skeletons or Zombies who had it equipped. Also if you fish it up which is rare.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make Chainmail armor in Minecraft PE, you can get it in creative, but it's uncraftable. If you play PC, here's a crafting recipe.[image: You might get fire by using commands]

Comment: Fire is no longer obtainable in PC using the `/give` command. It was removed in 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You can't craft it in survival. You can only get it from skeletons, zombies or loot chest from blacksmith chests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't craft it, but you can get it from villages' mineshaft' dungeons' nether fotresses' chests if you are lucky. And also they may drop from zombie or skeleton which wear chainmail armor, or the only other way that can do it, is to use mod
Chainmail armor mod: mcpeuniverse.com/mods/chainmail-armor-mod/
Good luck to you for finding the chainmail armor
Note that chainmail armor that drop from zombie / skeleton is already damaged.